# How to make organization chart like jstree

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I'm using jinja and I need to make organization tree chart like the logic is like in jstree.

Suppose the dataset was like this:

- employee : Anna

  - reports_to : None
- employee : Rudi

  - reports_to: Anna
- employee: Rocky

  - reports_to : Anna
- employee : Clara

  - reports_to : Rocky
- employee : Richard

  - reports_to : Rocky
- employee : Lyla

  - reports to : Clara
    ...

how do you sorting this dataset with the connection of reports_to?

I've tried to group this by reports_to but the result is like this

```
- None
    * Anna
- Anna
    * Rudi 
    * Rocky
- Rocky 
    * Clara
    * Richard
- Clara
    * Lyla
```

Here's some code

```
{% for data in employee_data|groupby("employee_name")%}
        <li>{{data.grouper}}</li>
            <ul>
                {% for item in data.list %}
                    <li>{{item.employee_name_for_report}}</li>
                    {% if not item.employee_name_for_report %}

                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

I expected something like this
    *

- None

  - Anna

    - Rudi
    - Rocky

      - Clara

        - Lyla
      - Richard

Comment: I don't understand the logic in your expected output. E.g., why "Rocky" is a sub-element of "Rudi"?

Comment: @Tsyvarev my bad rocky and rudi should be in the same sub